# communicating between main page and its iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

I have some kind of message board and I want visitors be able to attach files to their messages I'm using a iframe of a uploader script in my main page and also I’m using ajax for posting messages.

After uploading a file via the iframe how can I send it's information to the main page so it could be added that to the message body ?

E.g. put the information in the textfield. My jquery/ajax function checks that fields for values before submitting a message and include that if exist or something like that? but that text field is going to be in the iframe and my function is in the main page:

```
function post() {
    if($(iframe textfield).val() != '' ) {
        // add its value to the message body 
        $.ajax();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call function of main page from iframe page. See following example:

- test.html:

  ```
  <html>
  <body>
  <iframe src="testA.html"></iframe>
  <script>
  var response = function(data) {
      alert(data);
  }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- testA.html:

  ```
  <html>
  <body>
  <input type="button" onclick="window.top.response('hello');" value="Test" />
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same domain you can. From the parent you'd use `$('iframe').contents().find('element')`. From the iframe you'd use `$(window).parent().find('element')`

Comment: And if they're not on same domain then you can use [something different](http://tagneto.blogspot.com/2006/06/cross-domain-frame-communication-with.html)